# Having trouble running Log4J HelloWorld example, getting the "package does not exist" error

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm having issues running a Log4J example. I'm not sure if it's a configuration issues, or a coding issue. This is my sample code :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("pre_loggerDOTinfo");
        System.out.println();
        //logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);   //used to be.. 

        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        logger.warn("Hello, this is an WARN  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #2");
        logger.debug("Hello, this is an FATAL  message");


        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("post_loggerDOTinfo");

    }



}
```

But when I run this, I get the following error :

```
C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>javac HelloWorldLog4J.java
HelloWorldLog4J.java:1: error: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
                               ^
HelloWorldLog4J.java:2: error: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
                               ^
HelloWorldLog4J.java:3: error: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
                               ^
HelloWorldLog4J.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
                         ^
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class HelloWorldLog4J
HelloWorldLog4J.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable LogManager
  location: class HelloWorldLog4J
```

I believe my Classpath is set correctly, I have 3 variables set:

> **LOG4J_HOME** -  %log4j-api%;%log4j-core%
>
> **log4j-api** -
>   C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5-sources.jar
>
> **log4j-core** -
>   C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta5-sources.jar

And this is my directory structure ( [full-image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgS20.png) ) :

[image]

I was wondering if it's maybe the wrong version of log4j?  The version I have is this one :  apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin  , and [I downloaded it from this link](http://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/2.0-beta5/)

any tips appreciated, thanks

Comment: use `javac -cp path_to_jar1.jar:path_to_jar2.jar Example.java`

Comment: @Nomad -  I tried this, but still doesn't work  . . I'm wondering if it's an issue with code

Comment: @Nomad - OK i'm trying idea that James mentioned

Comment: Awesome, this one worked !! `C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>javac -cp  C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5
-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar HelloWorldLog4J.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the log4j jars to your CLASSPATH variable before you run javac. Alternatively, you can use the -cp option to specify the path there and then.

```
javac -cp <path> HelloWorldLog4J.java
```

where path is the absolute path to the log4j jars, each path separated by colon character (:). You should also include the current directory when using cp option, this is denoted by period character (.)

EDIT: You want to reference the jar files containing the class files for log4j, not java files e.g. log4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar, not log4j-core-2.0-beta5-sources.jar.

Comment: See my edit, you want jars containing class files, not sources jar.

Comment: Thanks !!! We got it to work !  `C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>javac -cp  C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5
-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar HelloWorldLog4J.java`

Comment: The interesting thing is that ... when I run this command with both JAR files, it does *not* work  -  `C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>javac -cp  C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5
-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar:C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar HelloWorldLog4J.java`

Comment: So I guess I don't really need to include the core JAR ?

Comment: However, it puts the same type of error later - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/lo
g4j/LogManager
        at HelloWorldLog4J.<clinit>(HelloWorldLog4J.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
`